# How to call a SAS STP in background using proc http and http_tokenauth

Tags: rest, url, sas

I'm trying to call a stored process (STP) from SAS via proc http using the option background, to ensure that my main process does not wait for the STP to be finished. I do use the following code:

```
filename resp "<path to response file>";
%let url = https://<ServerName>:<port>/SASStoredProcess/do;
%let question_mark = ?;

proc http
url="%str(&url.)&question_mark.%nrstr(_action=background&_program=<path to STP>&num1=11&num2=22)"
out=resp
http_tokenauth;
HEADERS "Content-Type"="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" "Accept"="application/json";
quit;
```

Unfortunately, in my response file I do always receive the SAS logon page.

Sending username/pw as part of my URL does work, but it is not wanted for security reasons. Hence I need to use http_tokenauth, which works for non background STPs.
Also, when I just paste my URL to the browser, it does work.

How can I ensure it does also work using proc http and http_tokenauth?

Additional Information:

Setup:

I do have a STP which is called by a process engine via REST and expects an immediate answer containing an ID.(Main STP)
This main STP then needs to call a sub STP containing a process, which will approx. take one hour to be finished. Hence I do not want the Main STP to wait for the sub STP to be finished.
Therefore the sub STP should be called in background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Token authentication only works when using "do**1**" instead of "do".
Referring to documentation:
https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=stpug&docsetTarget=n0ax7wadghvldwn1bbarfuly6adl.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en

Furthermore I'm using query to pass my parameters, which makes it more clear.

So this does work now:

```
%let url = https://<ServerName>:<port>/SASStoredProcess/do1;

proc http 
  url="%str(&url.)"
  query=("_action"             = "background"
         "_program"            = "<path to STP>"
         "num1"                = "1"
         "num2"                = "2"
         )
  ct="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  http_tokenauth
  out=resp;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off using `proc stp`, although this does mean your process will run under your session (not the SAS General Servers) identity.

If you really want to call STPs as part of your workstream, why not create a web interface and call the services that way?  The [SASjs](https://sasjs.io) framework can help you there, and anything you build will be immediately portable to SAS Viya.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My problem is, that the STP called needs to run in background, so the main process calling the STP does not wait for it to be finished. I will add my desired setup to the question so this is stated out more clearly.

Comment: If you add `inputparam _action="background";` will it still run in the background? For example: `proc stp program="/StoredProcesses/MySTP"; inputparam _action="background"; run;`

Comment: @StuSztukowski It unfortunately still does not run in background. When I add a sleep of 10 seconds it takes 14 and when I add one with 5 seconds it takes 9 seconds to finish.

Comment: Did you create your STP using Enterprise Guide? If so, this fix may explain it (resolved in m3): support.sas.com/kb/58/261.html  
For a programmatic way to create STPs, check out: core.sasjs.io/mm__createstp_8sas.html

Comment: No, I did create meta data for the STP in SAS management console and the code in SAS Stutio.